# getCurrentPosition in the React Native geolocation API is only running 10% of the time?

Tags: react-native

I am running the React Native getCurrentPosition Geolocation function within componentDidMount like this:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    alert('comp mounting');
    await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        alert("state of lat in callback is "+position.coords.latitude);
        this.setState({lat: position.coords.latitude, long: position.coords.longitude});

      },

      (error) => {alert("there was an error getting location")},

      {enableHighAccuracy: true}

      );
  }
```

It alerted the latitude the first time I ran it, and maybe a couple other times out of about 40 tries.  I think all of those runs were without `async` and `await`.  About 90% of the time neither the alert within the success callback nor the alert in the error callback run.

I put async and await in because I figured the request was taking too long (ran immediately the first time though).

I need to pass location information to a child component.

Is the React Native default Geolocation library just not very good or am I doing something wrong?  Should I switch to using the seperate iOS/Android geolocation options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert() calls appear to be the problem.  Once I removed the alert() calls it started working.